# Not able to update data using golang mongodb

Tags: go

```
func (s *MongoClient) UpdateProduct(person models.Person)(*mongo.SingleResult) {
    filter := bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$eq": person.ID}}

    update := bson.M{
        "$set":bson.M{
            "firstname": person.Firstname,
            "lastname": person.Lastname,
        },
    }
    collection := s.client.Database("thepolyglotdeveloper").Collection("group")
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)

    result:= collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, filter,update)
    return result
}
```

Comment: Is there a question? Guessing from the title, it looks like it is not finding anything to update. What is the type of person.ID?

Comment: Please provide more details? The title is not meant to be the question, add the details, what is the error message you are seeing, or if not,what happens, what do you see in the db, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)’s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too - despite its harsh title.